# Can someone [phone] the burninator?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

So, the [phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone) tag has the following description:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG! Use a more specific tag instead, e.g.: [windows-phone-8], [android] or [ios].

That alone kind of tells you that it should be burninated. However, for consistency, here are the criteria:

- No, it doesn't unambiguously describe the content at all.
- Questions tagged with this may or may not be on topic here.
- The tag doesn't add any useful information. If you used a more specific tag, like [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), the [phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone) tag adds nothing useful; if you *didn't*, then you should have.
- Yeah, I guess it *sort of* means the same thing in all common contexts, it's just not all that specific.

Comment: It was burninated finally

Comment: How unusual.  I got a 404 page the first time I tried to visit this question.